# Converting nomogram to logistic regression coefficients and intercept

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, regression-coefficients

My plan is to use a published nomogram to predict events in my data set. The question is, how do I derive logistic coefficients and intercept from the nomogram?

Comment: The nomogram you want to use has a reference somewhere? It's possible the coefficients of the logistic regression are clearly indicated in the reference work

Comment: No. And I have asked them to provide the coefficients but to no avail.

Comment: Can you post here the reference? A spurious approach could be constructing a dataset calculating the results and infer a regression equation in that dataset

Comment: Take this for example. Not the one that I want to use but close enough. 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167814011003343

Comment: I think you could build a data set with different values and compute a regression equation between them, maybe a digital approach using the lenght and absolute position of the Lines calculated using the nomogram image would be more precise